# The migration of questions to Expatriates, pertaining to nationality laws

Tags: discussion, migration

This question [united kingdom - UK EU settlment scheme, effects when acquiring British citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/21303/17166) was migrated from law to expatriates. (The original title was: **UK EU settlment scheme**, which is a bit misleading).

The main portion of the question was asking about the effects to their German and Polish citizenships after a possible acquirement of British citizenship.

Such a question can only be properly answered based on **nationality laws** and in this case also a special **Brexit transition law**.

It would be better if such questions remained in law and not be migrated.

Answer (score 3):

When a question, such as this one, is suited for two or more sites, it should be a matter of choice for the questioner to decide which site the question is to be asked on. Insofar as the question *is* a legal question and not "where do you find unsweetened peanut butter in Norway?", the risk in asking on LSE is that there may be a lower percentage of users who have experience with immigration issues in the EU. The counter-risk of Expat is the probability of not getting a good legal answer. In this case, it all worked out, but in general, I don't see that migrating an on-topic question to an alternative site is justified.

Answer (score 1):

> **Expatriates Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people living abroad on a long-term basis.

> **Law Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law.

**Questions about migration law fit on both sites.**

Remembering that **legal advice** is not appropriate for *either* site; they should be put on the site where they are more likely to be seen by people with the relevant experience to answer. All expatriates have dealt with migration law, very few legal scholars have.